# How to refresh display more often for a long script in PHP

Tags: php, refresh

I search a way to refresh display more often on a long script.
I.e. :

```
for($i=0;$i<=100000;$i++) {

<!-- 
some long process code 
-->

echo 'content:'.$i.' - ';

}
```

I launch it on Chrome. Currently, echo data appeared every 30 seconds. I would like a shorter delay for the refreshing echo display.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To push script's output to the browser call `flush()` periodically, i.e:

```
for($i=0;$i<=100000;$i++) {
  echo 'content:'.$i.' - ';

  if( $i%100 ) {
    flush();
  }
}
```

also check your [output buffering settings](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at output buffering.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php